# sql column decimal 20,6 format remove zerofill

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In my database table I have 8 columns with `decimal(20,6)` format.

Type of values will be inserted into the table is:-

- 1.59
- 2.155
- 2.5

In my table I saw,

- 1.590000
- 2.155000
- 2.500000

How can I make it formated as 1.59,2.155,2.50? I use both phpmyadmin and mysql command.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I did not define zerofill. MySQL is filling automatically when i change to decimal :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you alter table by doing `DECIMAl(10,2)` or

For only selection

`SELECT columnname1, ROUND(columnname2,2) AS RoundedValue FROM tablename;`

Comment: I am not allowed to alter the table but the second solution works! Thanks!